# Control the fadeout and fadein of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like the #preview to blink every sec as I make changes to `#companyName`.

Also, I would like the blinking of `#preview` to stop 1 sec after I stop making changes to `#companyName` for 2sec.

```
  <html>
      <body>
          <div id="edit">
                  <label>Company Name: </label>
                  <input type="text" id="companyName" />
          </div>
          <div id="preview">
                  <label id="preview" style ="font-size: 20px;">
                          This is my company
                  </label>
          </div>
      <script>

      $('#companyName').keyup(function() {
          delay(function(){
            var value = $(this).val();
            $('#preview').fadeOut().fadeIn();  
            $("#preview").text(value);
            
          }, 2000 );
      });

      
      var delay = (function(){
        var timer = 0;
        return function(callback, ms){
          clearTimeout (timer);
          timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
        };
      })();

      </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: I updated the script with what I have tried.

Comment: answer in jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/KRYQ8/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to blink the #preview on keyup and get it back after 2secs what you can do is,

```
$('#companyName').keyup(function() {
     var $prev=$('#preview').fadeOut().fadeIn();   
     delay(function(){          
        $prev.html($(this).val()).fadeIn();  
     }, 2000 );
});
```

Hope this helped. !

### Edit

Delay function should be like below,

```
var delay = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();
```

here i have seen you have hard coded 1000ms that wont work i guess.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to achieve is. After I have stopped typing for 2 sec. The blinking should stop. When I have a really long sentence, the blinking goes on.

Comment: in this case i guess you have to use setTimeout method not the delay event.     $('#companyName').keyup(function() {
        var $prev=$('#preview').fadeOut().fadeIn();
        setTimeout(function(){
            $prev.html($(this).val()).fadeIn();
        },2000);
         
    });

Comment: here is a working sample [link](http://jsfiddle.net/QU2Yb/) as soon as you complete final input it will automatically stop after 2sec. Because for every keyup it will fire this event thats why it holds some time. But if you want you can combine this with delay method so that timeout function will call after sometime.

Comment: I looked at your fiddle. Did you try entering the value ? Because the value is not getting updated.

Comment: here is the modified version, $(document).ready(function() {    
     $('#companyName').keyup(function() { 
         var $this=$(this);
         var $prev=$('#preview').fadeOut().fadeIn(); 
         setTimeout(function(){ 
             $prev.html( $this.val()).fadeIn(); 
         },2000); });
});